# Does the flag -r8 in ifort affect the variables declared as real*4?

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran, compiler-flags

The ifort compiler describes the flag -r8 as:

```
   -r8    Makes default real and complex variables  8  bytes  long.  REAL
          declarations are treated as DOUBLE PRECISION (REAL(KIND=8)) and
          COMPLEX  declarations  are  treated  as  DOUBLE  COMPLEX  (COM-
          PLEX(KIND=8)).
```

Does this mean that only the variables that are declared as real are casted into `real*8`, or that every real (even, say `real*4`) is casted into `real*8`?

Comment: It's never even crossed my mind that the compiler might override an explicit kind declaration, even a non-standard one such as `real*4`.  But if the thought did cross my mind I'd code up a little test and find out.  Why don't you ? It should only take you 5 minutes or so.

Comment: Yep, it took me 5 minutes to test.

Answer (score 1):

The manual clearly states the flag is about **default** real and complex variables. `Real*4` declarations are often made for a reason and the compiler should not change these when the default kind is changed.